# Creative sets (Jockush-Mohrherr)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computability

Recently I have found statement that claims:
(Jockusch-Mohrherr) Let A be any c.e. set except ω. Then A is creative iff (∀c.e.B) [A∩B=∅ ⇒ A ≡ A∪B].
But I couldn't find any proof of it. Can somebody help me prove this claim?

Comment: By $\equiv$, do you mean many-one equivalent or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference for creative set criterion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140304/reference-for-creative-set-criterion-theorem)