# Union of sets is creative

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, computational-mathematics

Let $A$ be any r.e. set except for $\mathbb{N}$. $A$ is creative $\implies$ $\forall$ r.e.(c.e.) set $B$ disjoint from $A$, it follows that $A∪B$ is creative.

The original is Theorem (Jockusch/Mohrherr) and possible solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140304/reference-for-creative-set-criterion-theorem). Thanks in advance for any advices or some solution

Comment: Why do you make an exception for $\mathbb N$? $\mathbb N$ isn't creative, is it?

Comment: Actually, it's the theorem (Jockusch/Mohrherr) and also there is [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140304/reference-for-creative-set-criterion-theorem), but I can't understand that union of sets is creative.